# Why doesn't mysqld produce output?

Tags: mysql-5.7

I have been upgrading Percona mysql to 5.7 on several servers recently, and often it goes like:

- Stop the daemon and install new packages.
- Start the daemon, which fails
- `su - mysql` and run `mysqld` manually to see what the problem is (normally a parameter has changed its name in my.cnf)

However, for some reason `mysqld` no longer writes any output; is there a parameter somewhere that controls this?

Comment: Is there nothing in the `/var/log/mysql/error.log` file when starting the daemon? 

Comment: @matigo No, nothing. If there are unknown parameters in ny.cnf, the daemon fails before it gets to opening the error log.